# Dynamic Allocation - user inputs elements without knowing the array size before runtime

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-allocation

so at run time we don't know the size of the array(matrix) and I want the user to input the elements of the array(matrix). is this the proper way to do it?Also did i return the pointer to the array properly?

```
#define MAX_DIM 10
int main(void)
{
    int done = 0;
    int rows, cols;
    float *dataMatrix;

    while (!done)
    {
    // Prompt user to enter row and column dimensions of matrix (must be > 0)
    do
    {
        printf("Enter row dimension (must be between 1 and %d): ", MAX_DIM);
        scanf("%d", &rows);

    } while(rows <= 0 || rows > MAX_DIM);
    do
    {
         printf("Enter column dimension (must be between 1 and %d): ", MAX_DIM);
         scanf("%d", &cols);
    } while(cols <= 0 || cols > MAX_DIM);

    dataMatrix = readMatrix(rows, cols);
    if (dataMatrix == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Program terminated due to dynamic memory allocation failure\n");
        return (0);
    }


float *matrix(int numRows, int numCols)    
{    
    int i=0;
    float **m= NULL;
    m=malloc(numRows*sizeof(float*));
    if(m==NULL)
    {
       printf("error\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<numRows;i++)
    {
       m[i]=malloc(numCols*sizeof(float));
    }
    if(m[i-1]==NULL)
    {
       printf("error\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter values for the matrix: ");
    scanf("%f",m[i]);
    return m[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this the proper way to do it?

You are heading in the right direction but not fully there.

> Also did i return the pointer to the array properly?

No.

You can allocate memory for a matrix using one of two methods.

1. Allocate `numRows` numbers of `float*`s. For each row, allocate `numCols` of `float`s and then return a pointer to the array of `float*s`. This is what you tried but you didn't do everything right.

   Take a closer look at the modified code for reading user data and the `return` statement.

   ```
   float **matrix(int numRows, int numCols)    
   {    
       int i=0;
       float **m = malloc(numRows*sizeof(float*));
       if(m == NULL)
       {
          printf("error\n");
          exit(1);
       }

       for(i=0; i<numRows; i++)
       {
          m[i] = malloc(numCols*sizeof(float));
          if(m[i] == NULL)
          {
             printf("error\n");
             exit(1);
          }
       }

       printf("Enter values for the matrix: ");
       for (i = 0; i < numRows; ++i )
       {
          for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j)
          {
             scanf("%f", &m[i][j]);
          }
       }
       return m;
   }
   ```
2. Allocate `numRows*numCols` of `float`s. Treat the 1D array as holder of 2D data. Use appropriate offsets to treat the 1D array as a 2D array. Return a pointer to the array of `float`s.

   ```
   float *matrix(int numRows, int numCols)    
   {    
       int i=0;
       float *m = malloc(numRows*numCols*sizeof(float));
       if(m==NULL)
       {
          printf("error\n");
          exit(1);
       }
       printf("Enter values for the matrix: ");
       for (i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
       {
          for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j)
          {
             int index = i*numCols+j;
             scanf("%f", &m[index]);
          }
       }
       return m;
   }
   ```